# I am trying to do a project by using Java. how can I display text file in Unicode format on JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, utf-8, fonts, jtextarea

how can I solve such a problem and display the content of a text file on the JTextAra?
the entire program was as follows:

```
public class TextAreaSample extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new TextAreaSample();
        }
    
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (ae.getSource() == bt) {
                File f;
                String filepath;
                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
                fc.showOpenDialog(null);
                f = fc.getSelectedFile();
                filepath = f.getAbsolutePath();
               
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filepath);
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis);        
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    ta.read(br, "utf-8");                       
    
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.out.println("file not found");
    
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("not oppend");
                }        
            }
            if (ae.getSource() == bt2) {
                ta.setText(" ");
                //.setText(" ");        
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Comment: 1) Unicode is not a format but an encoding. The trick to getting the characters to display is to use a font that supports the characters of interest. 2) The loading code can be simplified one there is a `Reader`, use [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,java.lang.Object)). 3) In every catch, either implement logging or call `ex.printStackTrace()` 4) There is no need to extend frame in this (or most) code.